# When compiling a custom kernel modules_install results in an error

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel

I am trying to install a custom kernel and all goes fine except when i run make `modules_install` it results in the following:

```
ln: target ‘/lib/modules/4.2.0-rc4/source’ is not a directory
Makefile:1120: recipe for target '_modinst_' failed
make: *** [_modinst_] Error 1
```

I looked up line number 1120 in Makefile and it contained this:

```
_modinst_:
    @rm -rf $(MODLIB)/kernel
    @rm -f $(MODLIB)/source
    @mkdir -p $(MODLIB)/kernel
```

I googled a lot and all i found was it occurred (mostly what i found) due to an extra space in the `EXTRAVERSION` variable in the Makefile but there is no space in my Makefile.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Edit :

I followed the suggestions in comments below and did 
`ls -al /lib/modules/4.2.0-rc4/`.
There is no source file or source directory present and running `modules_install` with the `make --trace` produces this:

```
Makefile:1120: target '_modinst_' does not exist
rm -rf /lib/modules/4.2.0-rc4/kernel
rm -f /lib/modules/4.2.0-rc4/source
mkdir -p /lib/modules/4.2.0-rc4/kernel
ln -s `cd . && /bin/pwd` /lib/modules/4.2.0-rc4/source
ln: target ‘/lib/modules/4.2.0-rc4/source’ is not a directory
Makefile:1120: recipe for target '_modinst_' failed
make: *** [_modinst_] Error 1
```

Comment: Have you tried it with `sudo`? Like `sudo make modules_install`?

Comment: I don't see any way that this rule can generate this error.  It doesn't invoke `ln` at all, and the only reference to `.../source` is in the `rm -f` command which doesn't expect `source` to be a directory.

Comment: Yes i run it with sudo because it requires those permissions.My bad for not mentioning before that "sudo make modules_install" resulted in this error.

Comment: @MadScientist I did all this a while ago on my system and it all went good without any problems but now this error.I am just clueless because I did not made any kind of changes to my kernel configuration whatsoever.

Comment: Well, you're going to have to investigate it yourself because nothing you've shown us will account for that.  The very first thing I would do is run `ls -al /lib/modules/4.2.0-rc4/.` and see what the permissions are for the directory, whether `source` is a file or directory and what its permissions are, etc.  If that's not enlightening you'll have to edit your makefile and start removing the `@` prefixes so that the commands make runs are printed and you can see them, or else use a newer version of GNU make with the `--trace` flag available.

Comment: @MadScientist I edited the post.Could you take a look?

Comment: `source is not a directory` means you have to clean up the file before trying again. @MadScientist, `make V=1` does the thing without modifying kernel sources.  Actually take a general rule of the kernel building: if you need to modify kernel sources you most likely do something *wrong*.

Comment: Andy: `make V=1` won't work here.  The rule as shown above uses literal `@` prefixes and those are not disabled with the kernel makefile's `V` variable.  Only if this rule used the `$(Q)` prefix would that work.  You either have to remove them by hand or else use `--trace` as I mentioned.  Also, see my answer for why this is not working: not sure what you mean by "clean up the file" but Abhinav's edited message shows that `source` already doesn't exist in that directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't include the entire rule that appeared at line 1120; there must have been more text after the `mkdir`, that you didn't show.  You need to show at least enough of the rule that we can see what might have gone wrong... in particular since your error message relates to `ln` you need to show the line containing the `ln` command.

However, based on the info you provided from `make --trace`, I'll bet I know what's wrong.

The problem is that the path to your working directory contains a directory with a space in the name.  In other words if you run `pwd` you'll see there's directory name with a space in it.  Or, possibly some other special character but most likely it's a space.

Don't do that: rename or move your current directory to someplace where the path doesn't contain a space.

Suppose your path is something like `/home/myself/My Source Code/info`.  Then the ln command is:

```
ln -s /home/myself/My Source Code/info /lib/modules/4.2.0-rc4/source
```

which is an invalid command, because each of those words is treated as a separate argument, as if you'd written:

```
ln -s '/home/myself/My' 'Source' 'Code/info' '/lib/modules/4.2.0-rc4/source'
```

Comment: It worked since i dont have enough reputation my vote is not visible yet but hopefully soon will be.Thanks !

Comment: Arguably this is a bug in the kernel makefile: if they quoted the recipe command line properly it would work.